# SVG g hides when parent g is set to a height

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am relatively new to SVG. I am plotting a chart which will dynamically plot temperature or wind value on x,y axis respectively. I am good with x-axis positioning.

But when it comes to Y-Axis, position come right but if the value is higher than parent chart height, it get cut off as you can see in the picture.

[image]

Need help on how to force visible the circle/element even it exceeds the parent element width or height?

Here is how mark up gets generated
[image]

I am using **d3.js** for this.

Here is the code for generating circle with text

```
  let svg = container
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height+(height*0.7));

        const chart = svg
            .append("g")
            .attr('class','chartwind')
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding.left + "," + (padding.top)  + ")")
 chart.append("path")
                .data(datapoints)
                .attr("class", "line wind-line")
                .style("stroke", colorScale("wind"))
                .style('stroke-width', '2px')
                .attr("d", windLine)

            let windPoint = chart.selectAll('g.windpoint').data(datapoints).enter().append('g').attr('class', 'windpoint').attr('transform', function (d) {
                return 'translate(' + (Math.round(xScale(d.parsedUtcDateTimeNow)) - 10) + ',' + yScale(d.windSpeed) + ')';
            })

            chart.selectAll('.windcircle')
                .data(Infos)
                .enter().append('circle')
                .attr("class", "windcircle")
                .style("stroke", colorScale("wind"))
                .style('stroke-width', '2px')
                .attr("cx", (d) => xScale(d.parsedUtcDateTimeNow))
                .attr("cy", (d) => {
                    return yScale(d.windSpeed);
                })
                .attr('r', 3)
                .style("fill", colorScale("wind"))

            windPoint
                .append('circle')
                .attr("cx", 0)
                .attr("cy", 0)
                .attr("r", function (d) {
                        return 8;
                })
                .attr("fill", "green")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0,-23)")

            windPoint
                .append('text')
                .attr("fill", "white")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0,-19)")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("font-size", "12px")
                .attr("font-weight", "600")
                .text((d) => {
                        return d.windGust;
                });

            windPoint
                .append('text')
                .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
                //.attr("transform","translate(0,5)")
                .text((d) => {
                    return d.windSpeed;
                });
```

Update

---

This is how I am constructing SVG height and width

```
 function getSizesById(id) {
        const container = document.querySelector(`#${id}`)
    
        if (!container)
            return null
    
        return {
            height: container.clientHeight,
            width: container.clientWidth,
        }
    }
            const { width, height } = (() => {
                return getSizesById(containerID)
            })()
  const { width, height } = (() => {
            return getSizesById(containerID)
        })(),

            padding = {
                ...size.padding,
                top: 20,
                bottom: 20
            },
            chartHeight = height - padding.bottom - padding.top,
            chartWidth = width - padding.left - padding.right
     

        const container = d3.select(`#${containerID}`)
    let svg = container
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);
```

Note: SVG height (or chart) should look with in the DIV and only when the data points go over the scale, then we need data to be visible over the div height.

Comment: <g> elements don't have width and height. They are always just the size of their childen. Best bet is to make the <svg> element bigger.

Comment: To say this more explicit: it is not the `<g>` element that cuts off the grafics, but the `<svg>` element. You must reserve enough vertical room to show not only your data points, but their assiciated grafic representation. You are not showing how the `<svg>` element is constructed, so I cannot give an answer. What you need to do is either increase the vertical downward translation of the `.chartwind` group, and possibly  increase the height of the `svg>` element , or set a `viewBox` attribute that encloses every possible grafical element that needs to be visible.

Comment: Hi @ccprog thanks for the comment, I update question with code on how I am constructing SVG. basically on load I am reading the container width and height from DOM and using that for SVG height and width with a fixed 20px padding.

Comment: @RobertLongson my SVG is constructed based on the area available in the DIV container. Is there a way to give padding for first g under svg ?

Comment: <g> elements can be translated e.g. transform="translate(0, 100)"

Answer (score 1):

`<g>` elements do not have any inherent size. They are only a logical wrapper for a group of markup tags, and a place to give them some common properties. What restricts the visible parts of your chart is the `<svg>` element.

Your code shows that each datapoint is represented by grafic elements that span a bounding box of `(-8 -31 16 35)` (left - top - width - height). This is how much space you need to show all of it.

Remove the `transform` attribute from your `.chartwind` group. The space you need to show the complete graph is

- left: lower boundary of your xScale range minus 8
- top: lower boundary of your yScale range minus 31 (in the downward coordinate system)
- width: extent of your xScale range plus 16
- height: extent of your yScale range plus 35

Add some padding if you like.

Add a [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) attribute with these four numbers to the `<svg>` element: `viewbox="<left> <top> <width> <height>"`. The area described like this will then be fitted inside the available space of the `<svg>` element, without you having to do any further figuring out of transformations.